# Where is the C++ new() function located within the gcc source code?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, malloc, new-operator

I understand the libstdc++ code is now bundled in with the libc code.I downloaded the full gcc 4.8.2 code from here:

http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.2/

However I cannot find any file called `new.c` or `new.cpp` which contains something resembling the `new()` called when allocating memory in a c++ program.

I did find `new_op.cc` but was not sure if this is the same runtime function? If not, where can I find the `new()` source code within the zip I linked to above?

Comment: `new` is a keyword, not a function.

Comment: @Slaks: wrong, `new` is an operator, exactly `::operator new`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, It's still a keyword by the standard's definition. See [lex.key].

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu GCC 4.8 is not exactly the GCC 4.8 provided by the FSF! Distributions are patching GCC. So get the Ubuntu source package. And the `::operator new` is in `libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new` (which gets installed as `<new>` header) and `libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_*.cc` files of GCC source.

Most of the job is done by `malloc` (called from `new_op.cc`) which is implemented inside `libc` and uses the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (and related) syscalls to change the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space). Syscalls are implemented in the kernel and are elementary atomic operations from inside an application (which will often execute a `SYSENTER` machine instruction to switch to kernel mode)

Comment: So if i understand you correctly new_op.cc is what i was after?

Comment: I basically want to be able to find out what C++ and C code is executed when new() is called from a C++ program. So my starting point was going to be the source code for new() and then presumably malloc()

Comment: Your quickly get into `mmap` and other syscalls. What would you do then? And a particular implementation of `::operator new` don't tell you all about its abstract specification.

Comment: re mmap, I presume you're pointing out mmap is in assembly? Thats not too bad because the purpose of my analysis is that I am explaining why a memory pool is so much quicker than using new() without a pool. I dont understand your last point about abstract specification?

Comment: No, `mmap` is a system call. From the application's point of view (in user-space) it is atomic.